# Can one http mutlipart request split up the file in multiple parts?

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, multipartform-data, resteasy

Does the file in a form send as different parts in a `multipart/form-data` request ?

I have to send a file as from my form to one REST end point .

```
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.InputPart;
import org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormDataInput;

public class BulkUploadTask {


    public void readFile(MultipartFormDataInput input) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException{

        Map<String, List<InputPart>> uploadForm = input.getFormDataMap();
        List<InputPart> inputParts = uploadForm.get("file");

        for (InputPart part : inputParts) {

            InputStream inputStream = part.getBody(InputStream.class, null);


        }
    }

}
```

This is the class which process the Multipart form data.

But I didn't understand why the RestEasy API method `getFormDataMap` returns a list of `InputPart` :

```
List<InputPart> inputParts = uploadForm.get("file");
```

Can this `file` be splitted as different Parts ?

Should I consider only the first part :

`uploadForm.get("file").get(0)`  ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you post a form, you send a list of key-value pairs, but each key can appear multiple times with different values. In programming this type of structure is known as a `ListMultimap` (or potentially SetMultiMap).

Forms are typically encoded using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which means that only string values are allowed. If you need to upload files, you need to use `multipart/form-data`, however the same key can still hold multiple values.

Multipart file does not mean that a **file** is split into multiple parts, it means that the **request** is split into multiple parts. Each part consist of a normal string based value, or a file (and metadata), and each parameter is separated by a boundary.

If you create a `multipart/form-data` form, and have 5 file-upload fields all named "file", and you uploaded a different file in each one, then `List<InputPart> inputParts = uploadForm.get("file");` would return a list of size 5, one for each different value for the key named "file".

In most cases the UI will only have a single upload field, and in that case I would just use `uploadForm.get("file").get(0)`, and possibly check the size of the list and throw an exception if the size was larger than 1 (or exactly 1 if the file is required).